How to upload file from local path using the utapi uploadFiles
I'm trying to upload files from disk without setting up and endpoint or getting from the client but when I use the utapi functions, they do not work directly with the file path or the buffer gotten with fs.readFile(path).
How do I transform the file so I would be able to upload using utapi.uploadFiles(files).
I'm working with Nextjs 14.
Here is where I instantiated the UTAPI:
const utapi = new UTApi({
    token: process.env.UPLOADTHING_TOKEN!,
});

Here is the function I'm using it from:
export async function UploadPowerpointToUploadThing(
    fileBuffer: Buffer,
    fileName: string
): Promise<UploadFileResult[]> {
    try {
        const file = new File([fileBuffer], fileName, {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
        });

        console.log("THIS IS UTAPI FILE BEFORE UPLOAD", file);

        const response = await utapi.uploadFiles([file]);

        console.log("THIS IS UTAPI RESPONSE AFTER UPLOAD", response);

        if (!response?.[0].data?.url) {
            throw new Error("Upload failed - No URL returned");
        }

        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error("Failed to upload powerpoint to uploadthing");
    }
}

